# MariaDB - Host is blocked because of many connection errors

Tags: mariadb

We have a simple monitoring that opens a TCP connection on port 3306 of the mariadb server to check if the server is reachable. mariadb logs this with the following message:

> [Warning] Aborted connection to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: 'xxx' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

after 100 of these connections, mariadb does not allow any further connections from the monitoring-host:

> Host 'IP' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mariadb-admin flush-hosts'

of course we could set max_error_connections much higher or flush hosts regularly - but that's not what we want

is there a way to allow a specific host to make unlimited connections? or how could we solve the problem?

Comment: Which client API does the monitoring tool use? Did you run `netstat -a` on both client and server machine (for checking tcp limits) ?

Comment: it's not about tcp limits. it's just mariadb that doesn't allow any more connections if there were too many bad ones. but we cannot change the monitoring

Comment: The solution is to find the reason for aborted connections, this could be a TCP problem. However this question should be moved to dba.stackexchange.

Comment: the "problem" is that the monitoring simply opens a tcp connection to check whether the mysql server is still there and then closes the connection directly (without authentication)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the abnormally noisiness of logs by pushing it down a warning level in  [MDEV-12274](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12274): Too many connections warning in error log ([#2213](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/2213)).

The max_connect_error was mentioned in [MDEV-21456](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21456) but I missed it. Attempts at a [fix](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/pull/2413) which is about to be reviewed.

There isn't a good workaround other than the two you've come up with for the time being.

Comment: I am running MariaDB 10.11.4 (Debian Bookworm) with `log-warnings=2`, but I still get these messages every time the monitoring connects. Shouldn't this be fixed?

Comment: I think you are right @Larsen, please report a bug.

Comment: Created https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-33368